# finding Q point of thyristor drive circuit.

Tags: transistors, transformer, power-electronics

how to find Q point of the transistor shown in the image. the problem is specifically due to pulse transformer.[image: thyristor drive circuit]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to find suitable SPICE models and do the simulation. In the beginning ignore the transofmer.

I know you are hoping that there is some simpler solution but if you going to do this on the paper it would take some time. I would use LTSpice/TINA TI and try to plot amplitude/frequency characteristics. After that the quality factor is the central frequency divided by fH(high frequency)-fL(low frequency). The values of the frequencies are where the amplitude is -3dB comparing to the amplitude on the central.

Comment: Firstly thanks !! Currently i am using Microcap and Orcad, and in these software there is no model of pulse transformer available. I want to know is there any equivalent model of pulse transformer that i can use or any other software in which model of Pulse Transformer is available ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no "Q" (quiescent) point in this type of circuit. This is not a linear amplifier. Instead, the switching transistor Q1 is either full on (saturated) or full off (cutoff), which is highly nonlinear. You basically need to analyze the two states separately.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, the transistor will be used in switching mode, thus alternating between the cut-off and saturation. My contribution, if you find it of some use, is to point its operation. I'm assuming you're using the thyristor in **integral control** mode (instead of **phase control** mode). Thus, to turn on the load (triggering the thyristor) applies a high-frequency signal (a few kHz), with a duty cycle of 50% and 24V amplitude at the primary of a pulse transformer. Assuming also that this transformer has a 1:1 ratio and that it blocks the DC component, then appear pulses on secondary with an approximate range of +/-12V. The diode rectifies this signal and a capacitor (my addition to the circuit) can help create a single 12V pulse to trigger the triac. In summary, the idea is to create a pulse of long duration through a transformer which is not happy with DC. Please, note this is an extremely idealized behavior, neglecting losses in the diodes, transformer, ...

[image: Integral Control]